# .NET CORE 2.1 Constructor asks for IConfiguration

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, .net-core, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-2.1

I've followed several methods on StackOverflow to fix my issue, none with a result:

My `DefaultConnection`-string is in my `AppSettings.json`. To retrieve info I am reading to use the `IConfiguration` from my `startup.cs`. The constructor of my MsSQL-context is still asking for this IConfiguration. Note: I'm using a repository pattern.

startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

I've added the Singleton in my startup after a suggestion. With or without this the constructor of MsSQLContext is still requesting this as a variable to be passed. Leaving the constructor without this gives me the error: `Connectionstring not initialized`.

AdminMsSQLContext:

```
        private readonly string _connectionString;


    public MSSQLAdminContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify this question.  I do not seem to see the issue here.  Also, if you do not mind can you post your appsettings.json

Comment: As in my post: The constructor of my MsSQL-context is still asking for this IConfiguration. Even though through DI it should not request for it, it still does.

Comment: I guess I am still missing the issue.  You need to inject the connection string into your constructor.  How else will it know how to get it?

Comment: Through Dependency Injection it should use it. It's not picking up on the Injection and asks me to pass through an instance IConfiguration. DI should've injected that on startup. I'm unable to use the instance of IConfiguration that's made during startup through the startup.cs file in my example.

Comment: You can also construct your DB context in your startup file, then inject it wherever you need it.  I final option is to make a configuration object and use the IOptions pattern to get your connection string.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  It is failing to inject the IConfiguration.....  have you registered MSSQLAdminContext with the DI container?

Comment: As it's my first time using this particular method, I'm uncertain how to register this into a DI container. Giving a quick browse through StackOverflow doesn't help me. Would you like to answer the question, and show me where in startup I register such things?

Comment: just did!!  Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injecting `IConfiguration` is actually an anti-pattern, anyways. What you should be doing is supplying an action to your scope registration and change your `MSSQLAdminContext` class to accept just the connection string in its constructor:

```
public MSSQLAdminContext(string connectionString)
{
    _connectionString = connectionString ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
}
```

Then:

```
services.AddScoped(_ =>
    new MSSQLAdminContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection)));
```

Your repo should not have knowledge of something like your configuration. If it needs a connection string, then it should take the connection string, and that is all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having is that you have not registered the `MSSQLAdminContext` with the DI container.  Because of this the DI engine does not know to inject the `IConfiguration` into the class.  In your start up you will register this class however you need, I tend to use scoped for these types of classes you may use in multiple places.  So something like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<MSSQLAdminContext>();
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        }
```

Comment: Adding this will make it registered, but my debugger is still telling my I need to pass IConfiguration. Even after rebuilding.